# Incorrect result for finding which day of the week that the first day of a month falls to

Tags: c, time.h

I have the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
struct tm tm;
int startDayOfWeek;
int findStartDateInMonth(int month,int year)       
{
    tm.tm_mon = month;
    tm.tm_year = year - 1900;
    tm.tm_mday = 1;
    tm.tm_hour = tm.tm_min = tm.tm_sec = 0;
    tm.tm_isdst = -1;
    if(mktime(&tm) != -1)
    {
        startDayOfWeek = tm.tm_wday;
    }
    return startDayOfWeek;
}
int main(void) {

char *wday[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
int a = findStartDateInMonth(8,2018);
if(mktime(&tm) != -1)
    printf("%s\n", wday[tm.tm_wday]);
  return 0;
}
```

The code returns Saturday, which is wrong since August 1st, 2018 is Wednesday.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

There's a trap in the definition of `struct tm`:

```
int tm_mday; // day of the month — [1, 31]
int tm_mon;  // months since January — [0, 11]
```

That is, `tm_mday` is 1-based, but `tm_mon` is 0-based. Setting it to `8` means you're looking at September 1, not August 1 (and 2018-09-01 is indeed a Saturday).

Try

```
tm.tm_mon = month - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

[You can see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) that `tm_mon` has a 0-11 range.

So you need to subtract 1 to `tm_mon` when assignating it.

```
tm.tm_mon = month - 1;
```

This should solve your problem.